# как правильно посчитать сумму по столбцу mysql через PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

```
$query = "SELECT sum(load_d) FROM  `aser` WHERE Y=3";
$stmt = $this->pdo->query($query);

while ($row = $stn->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  print "-----------------\n";
  print $row['load_d'];
}
```

подскажите почему не работает возврат суммы столбца через PDO? sql запрос верный, проверял через phpmyadmin.

Comment: А почему Вы решили, что там будет колонка X ? ее там скорее всего нет

Comment: @KoVadim почему нет? я знаю что она есть и в phpmyadmin данный запрос срабатывает и выдает результат

Comment: php admin показывает, что в результирующей выборке есть колонка с именем X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO несколько умнее других устаревших API, и не требует никаких специальных трюков с запросом для получения суммы.

```
$query = "SELECT sum(load_d) FROM  `aser` WHERE Y=3";
$sum = $this->pdo->query($query)->fetchColumn();
echo $sum;
```

отдельно хочу отметить что использование цикла для получения одной строки не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 2):

Запрос верный, имя колонки - неверное.

```
$query = "SELECT sum(X) as sum_value FROM  `table` WHERE Y=3";
$stmt = $this->pdo->query($query);

while ($row = $stn->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
print "-----------------\n";
print $row['sum_value'];
```